# Creating project structure in eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, war

I have a source code folder with following structure

```
main
    - java (folder structure for java files)
    - resources 
        - META-INF
        - ESAPI.properties
        - importdata.properties
    - webapp
        - resources
            - jar files
            - templates
            - styles
            - scripts
        - WEB-INF
            - spring(webmvc-config.xml)
            - views (jsp files)
            - web.xml
            - other files
```

As my knowledge this project is web application build on `spring framework`. I do not have any eclipse workspace for this.

Now I have to build `war` file by upgrading few features. How can I make appropriate `workspace/project structure` to develop and deploy the system?

Comment: If there is a `pom.xml` file, open the directory containing the `pom.xml` via _File > Open Projects from File System_.

Comment: Not in a source directory but we have old war file where I can find `pom.properties` and `pom.xml` file inside `META-INF>maven>com.xx.xx>PRO`